# simple node server returning "Cannot GET/"

Tags: node.js

I have this simple server and when I go to localhost:3000 I get "Cannot GET /" I t fails when I try and call /register as well. Any ideas? thanks

```
var express = require('express');
var gcm = require('node-gcm');
var apn = require('apn');

var app = express();
var device_token;

 /*
 , function(){
 var host = server.address().address;
 var port = server.address().port;
 console.log(port, host);
 }
*/
 app.listen(3000);

 app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With,    Content-Type, Accept");
   next();
 });

app.post('/register', function(req, res){
   device_token = req.body.device_token;
   console.log('device token received');
   console.log(device_token);

   res.send('ok');
});
```

Comment: I don't know anything about node js express but their documentation shows calling listen() after you define the handlers- does it work if you do that?

Comment: doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Navigating to a page in your browser is a `GET` request. You've only defined a handler for a `POST` request for the route `/register`:

```
app.post('/register', function(req, res){
   device_token = req.body.device_token;
   console.log('device token received');
   console.log(device_token);

   res.send('ok');
});
```

You haven't defined any thing for the `/` route. So when you navigate to either, it rightfully throws `Cannot GET` becuase either that route itself isn't defined, ie for `/`, or the `GET` method for that route isn't defined, ie. for `/register`.

You can allow a `GET` request at the root url ( `/` ) with:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('Hello!')
})
```

For the `/register` route, you should not use a `GET` request because you need to send information in the request body to actually register a user. ( Only post requests allow this ).

You've set it up correctly. You just can't view it in the browser. Test it out with [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or curl to see if it works.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. However, when I look in my console, I see: Failed to load resource http://localhost:3000/register

Comment: @BillPope you can't load a server's route on a client. You can only load files on the client. Thats why you're seeing failed to load resource because there is nothing there to load.  You should be posting to the server's route with something like. `$.ajax('/register', data)`

Comment: I tried it in postman and this part is failing: device_token = req.body.device_token;

Comment: you have to send the post request as **x-www-form-urlencoded**.

Comment: @BillPope express doesn't ship with a body parser middleware. You have to install one. You can use [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.org/package/body-parser). Check the express docs for more info: http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body

Comment: Ok. That will probably solve my problem with postman but I think calling it from my app is putting up a cross-domain problem since it's response in the status is 0. Meaning, it's not even sending the headers or anything. I thought that's why I set those headers to run to allow it!? I don't believe it's working. But it's not giving me the usual cross-domain error which makes me wonder.

Answer (score 1):

You have no defined route for `/`. `/register` does not work because you have `app.post`, which only accepts POST requests. If you want the `GET` request to `/register` to work, add this piece of code:

```
app.get('/register', function(req, res) {
    res.send("It works!");
});
```

Comment: could I define app.get('/') then define app.post('/register' ...?

Comment: Sure you can. It doesn't really matter in which order you put the various routes, unless you are using `next`.